# Connect to gRPC server with Socket Java NIO but server not response

Tags: sockets, nio, grpc, grpc-java

My gRPC Java Client connect to Server Java NIO with socket and NIO transported request's Client to server gRPC but server not response.

My client gRPC code:

```
        private final  ManagedChannel channel;
        private final  MyServiceProviderGrpc.MyServiceProviderBlockingStub blockingStub;
        private final  MyServiceProviderGrpc.MyServiceProviderStub asyncStub;

        public ClientGrpc(String host, int port) 
        {
            this(ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port).usePlaintext(true));
        }
        ClientGrpc(ManagedChannelBuilder<?> channelBuilder) 
        {
            channel = channelBuilder.build();
            blockingStub = MyServiceProviderGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
            asyncStub = MyServiceProviderGrpc.newStub(channel);         }

        public void greet(String name)          {
            logger.info("Will try to greet " + name + " ...");
            TemperatureRequest request = TemperatureRequest.newBuilder().setQuestion(name).build();
            TemperatureResponse response;
            try 
            {
              response = blockingStub.getTemperature(request);
            } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) 
            {
              logger.info("RPC failed: {0}"+ e.getStatus());
              return;
            }
            logger.info("Greeting: " + response.getAnswer());       }


ClientGrpc clients = new ClientGrpc("localhost",4321);
clients.greet("bap");
```

I get a message in NIO:

> PRI * HTTP/2.0
>
> SM

Comment: Are you also using gRPC on the server?  It looks like the server (or proxy) you are connecting to doesn't support http2

Comment: Yes, my server using gRPC C++. Thank for your answer, my problem be solved. The socket NIO transported wrong byte from gRPC client.